# AS3 Creating multidimensional-array from xml

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, multidimensional-array, 2d

I want to create a nested arrays. Here is my code, after I loaded xml.

```
 function readXML(event:Event):void
 {
 _data = new XML(event.target.data);
 for each (var usr in _data.item)
 {
 allUserbase.push({name: usr.@name,state: usr.@state, 
 complex:  usr.complex,image:usr.@image, link: usr.@link});
 for (var k:int = 0; k< allUserbase.length; k++){
 trace(k, allUserbase[k].complex);
 for (var t:int = 0; t< allUserbase[k].length; t++){
 trace(k,t, allUserbase[k][t]);
 // this part when i try to built 2d array doesnt work.. :(*/
 }
```

Here is my XML:

```
   <content>
   <item image="John.jpg" name="John" state = "New Jersey" >
   <complex fid = "0"> mg749</complex>  
   <complex fid = "1"> ks749</complex>  
   <complex fid = "2"> ks678</complex>      
   </item>    
   <item image="Smith.jpg" name="Smith" state = "California">  
   <complex fid = "0"> we649</complex>  
   <complex fid = "1"> sd449</complex>  
   <complex fid = "2"> df459</complex>  
   <complex fid = "3"> hj569</complex>      
   </item>  
   <item image="Smith.jpg" name="Mike" state = "New York">  
   <complex fid = "0"> 8794</complex>  
   <complex fid = "1"> 4384</complex>     
   </item> 
   </content>;
```

Comment: Is this the third time you've asked the same question in 3 days? and not accepted any of the old answers?

Comment: Oh yeah, I knew I saw this question before.

Comment: @Mike and @Taurayi -yes, i did'nt got my answer and was desperate but thanks a lot for help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the following along the lines of what you want?:

```
var contentXml:XML =        
<content>
    <item image="John.jpg" name="John" state = "New Jersey" >
        <complex fid = "0"> mg749</complex>  
        <complex fid = "1"> ks749</complex>  
        <complex fid = "2"> ks678</complex>      
    </item>    
    <item image="Smith.jpg" name="Smith" state = "California">  
        <complex fid = "0"> we649</complex>  
        <complex fid = "1"> sd449</complex>  
        <complex fid = "2"> df459</complex>  
        <complex fid = "3"> hj569</complex>      
    </item>  
    <item image="Smith.jpg" name="Mike" state = "New York">  
        <complex fid = "0"> 8794</complex>  
        <complex fid = "1"> 4384</complex>     
    </item> 
</content>; 

var contentArray:Array = new Array();

for each(var item in contentXml.item)
{
    var itemArray:Array = new Array();
    itemArray.push(item.@image, item.@name, item.@state);

    contentArray.push(itemArray);

    for each(var complex in item.complex)
    {
        var complexArray:Array = new Array();
        complexArray.push(complex.@fid, complex);

        itemArray.push(complexArray);

    }// end for each

}// end for each

trace(contentXml.item[0].@image); // outputs: John.jpg
trace(contentArray[0][0]) // outputs: John.jpg

trace(contentXml.item[0].complex[0]); // outputs: mg749
trace(contentArray[0][3][1]) // outputs: mg749
```

**[UPDATE]**

You can also use a combination of `Array` objects and `Dictionary` objects like the following:

```
var contentArray:Array = new Array();

for each(var item in contentXml.item)
{
    var itemDictionary = new Dictionary();
    itemDictionary["image"] = item.@image;
    itemDictionary["name"] = item.@name;
    itemDictionary["state"] = item.@state;

    var complexArray:Array = new Array();
    itemDictionary["complex"] = complexArray;

    contentArray.push(itemDictionary);

    for each(var complex in item.complex)
    {
        var complexDictionary:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
        complexDictionary["fid"] = complex.@fid
        complexDictionary["value"] = complex;

        complexArray.push(complexDictionary);

    }// end for each

}// end for each

trace(contentXml.item[0].@image); // outputs: John.jpg
trace(contentArray[0]["image"]) // outputs: John.jpg

trace(contentXml.item[0].complex[0]); // outputs: mg749
trace(contentArray[0]["complex"][0]["value"]) // outputs: mg749
```

Comment: Hi Taurayi, thanks a lot for help..this is awsome.. i am just confused about one thing, and pardon me if i am asking something stupid, but how do I "trace(contentXml.item[0].complex[2]); // outputs: ks678 trace(contentArray[0][3][1]); // outputs: mg749 how do i access "ks678" from here"... thanks a lot again for help..

Comment: @Taurayi..i got this too thanks a lot..dictionary objects works very well..I have one more question though i have to create a search function for this and I am bot able to get it right for complex, following s the code I am using: function search(MouseEvent):void { for (var n:int = 0; n<allUserbase.length; n++) { for (var k:int = 0; k<allUserbase[n].length; k++) { if ((allUserbase[n][k].complex.toLowerCase() == search_complex.text.toLowerCase() || search_complex.text=="")) { trace("found"); } } } }

Answer (score 0):

`{name: usr.@name,state: usr.@state, 
 complex:  usr.complex,image:usr.@image, link: usr.@link}` is not an `Array`, but an `Object` declaration, its elements can be accessed by `allUserbase[k].complex` or `allUserbase[k].['complex']`, they don't have a numeric index.

Comment: thnx for replying. How do i access compplex data by creating a 2d array lilke allUserbase[0][1]..is there a way to do so..